# sql database syntax error near '.'

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I get error reading database.Incorrect syntax near '.'.
Here is my sql Query. Is there anything I should change?

```
SELECT
    Item.item_id AS 'ID',
    Item.item_type AS 'Item Type',
    Item.item_description AS 'Item Description',
    Item.purchase_year AS 'Purchase Year',
    Item.purchase_price AS 'Purchase Price',
    Player.fname AS 'First Name',
    Player.lname AS 'Last Name',
    Player.sport AS 'Sport',
    Player.position AS 'Position',
    Player.team_f AS 'Current Team',
    Item.inscription AS 'Inscription',
    Item.dedication AS 'Dedication',
    Item.condition AS 'Condition',
    Item.value AS 'Estimate Value'
FROM Item
INNER JOIN Player
    ON Item.player_id = Player.player_id
WHERE Item.item_type LIKE @SearchPam
OR Item.item_description LIKE @SearchPam
OR Player.fname LIKE @SearchPam
OR Player.lname LIKE @SearchPam
OR Player.sport LIKE @SearchPam
OR Player.position LIKE @SearchPam
OR Player.team_f LIKE @SearchPam
OR Player.team_s LIKE @SearchPam
OR Player.team_t LIKE @SearchPam
```

Comment: I don't get any syntax error when I run the query. Are you sure that's the actual query that you get the error for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change your whole approach. You should be using table aliases, you need to normalize your data (team_f, team_s is an indication you have repeating columns), you need to format your code so it is legible instead of shoving dozens of lines into one. I am concerned that you have LIKE on every single predicate. If this has a leading wildcard your performance is going to be awful. The last change I would make would be to use stored procedures instead of pass through sql so you can separate data from the application.

```
SELECT i.item_id AS ID
    , i.item_type AS ItemType
    , i.item_description AS ItemDescription
    , i.purchase_year AS PurchaseYear
    , i.purchase_price AS PurchasePrice
    , p.fname AS FirstName
    , p.lname AS LastName
    , p.sport AS Sport
    , p.position AS Position
    , p.team_f AS CurrentTeam
    , i.inscription AS Inscription
    , i.dedication AS Dedication
    , i.condition AS Condition
    , i.value AS EstimateValue 
FROM Item AS i
INNER JOIN Player AS p ON i.player_id = p.player_id 
WHERE i.item_type LIKE @SearchPam 
    OR i.item_description LIKE @SearchPam 
    OR p.fname LIKE @SearchPam 
    OR p.lname LIKE @SearchPam 
    OR p.sport LIKE @SearchPam 
    OR p.position LIKE @SearchPam 
    OR p.team_f LIKE @SearchPam 
    OR p.team_s LIKE @SearchPam 
    OR p.team_t LIKE @SearchPam
```

Comment: Thanks for the catch on the missing alias @M. Grue. The AS word is not required but many people prefer it.

Comment: One additional thing I changed in my query that I did not mention in my response is that you shouldn't wrap column aliases in single quotes. The best approach is to remove spaces from column names but if you really think you need to it is better to wrap the name in [square brackets].

Comment: No Problem - Yeah, but i added it as it was the point of you feedback - Makes it easy to read :)